# Operator overloading in python with the object on the right hand side of the operator

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I recently learned about operator overloading in python and I would like to know if the following is possible.

Consider the following hypothetical/contrived class.

```
class My_Num(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __add__(self, other_num):
        if isinstance(other_num, My_Num):
            return self.val + other_num.val
        else:
            return self.val + other_num
```

I know that the way that's written above, I can do things like this

```
n1 = My_Num(1)
n2 = My_Num(2)
n3 = 3
print n1 + n2
print n1 + n3
```

and those will work as expected.  I also know that the way it's currently written I can't do this

```
n1 = My_Num(1)
n2 = 2
print n2 + n1
```

Is there any way around this?  I know this example is contrived but I have an application in which it would be very useful if when I did operator overloading, the class for which I define the operator can appear on the right hand side of operator.  Is this possible in python?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. For example, there is [`__radd__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__). Also, [there are none](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) for `__le__()`, `__ge__()`, etc., but as Joel Cornett rightly observes, if you define only `__lt__`, `a > b` calls the `__lt__` function of `b`, which provides a workaround.

```
>>> class My_Num(object):
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.val = val
...     def __radd__(self, other_num):
...         if isinstance(other_num, My_Num):
...             return self.val + other_num.val
...         else:
...             return self.val + other_num
... 
>>> n1 = My_Num(1)
>>> n2 = 3
>>> 
>>> print n2 + n1
4
>>> print n1 + n2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'My_Num' and 'int'
```

Note that in at least some cases it's reasonable to do something like this:

```
>>> class My_Num(object):
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.val = val
...     def __add__(self, other_num):
...         if isinstance(other_num, My_Num):
...             return self.val + other_num.val
...         else:
...             return self.val + other_num
...     __radd__ = __add__
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is __radd__ the only one that allows that?  The specific operators that I need to overload for my application are the >> and the << operators.  Am I just out of luck it I want to do this for those operators?

Comment: Nope. Did you click on the link? There's `__rrshift__`, and so on.

Comment: It's possible to right compare to a limited extent by controlling which operators are defined for each class. If A and B only have __lt__ defined, for example. A<B and B>A will call the method belonging to the little end.

Comment: Is there any way to change the associativity of an opeartor?  For example, could I make the >> operator right associative?

Comment: @martega, _that_, I _highly_ doubt. But I don't actually know.

Answer (score 2):

You have to overload the `__radd__` method (right-side addition). Your function should look pretty much the same as your `__add__` method, e.g.:

```
def __radd__(self, other):
     return self.val + other.val
```