# Python int dunder methods return NotImplemented

Tags: python, magic-methods

What really happens under the hood with `1/3.5` (or `1+3.5` or `1-3.5`)?

### Preface

I will use division as example but this is true for all the methods

In my code I need to use operations as functions.
I found method `__truediv__` inside both `int` and `float`.
I do

```
div = int.__truediv__
```

and then use it as:

```
div(a,b)
```

After some testing and some troubleshooting, I found that `div` returns `NotImplemented` instead of some number when there is a float inside.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 3.5
>>> a/b
0.2857142857142857
>>> int.__truediv__(a, b)
NotImplemented
>>> float.__truediv__(a, b)
TypeError: descriptor '__truediv__' requires a 'float' object but received a 'int'
```

What I found to be working is:

```
>>> float.__truediv__(float(a), float(b))
0.2857142857142857
```

Honestly I don't like this, but most of all, *I don't understand* what `1/3.5` is really doing!
Is it casting to float under the hood? I know that `3/1 = 3.0` but I hope the answer is somewhat different.

If I use directly the int methods, the problem is the same:

```
>>> a.__truediv__(b)
NotImplemented
>>> a.__rtruediv__(b)
NotImplemented
```

### Going Back to title

As far as I know `a OPERATION b` gets `a` as main object, and uses a dunder method to evaluate result of operation with `b`.

```
a.__operation__(b)
```

But in `int` dunder methods I see that `b` must be `int` too, for example:

```
int.__add__(1, 3.5)
NotImplemented
```

After some hours of research I didn't find what it does under the hood. I searched source code, to find the int class but I had no success in understanding it at all.

I found 2 solutions in my code, and will test if one is better than the other, for example, for addition:

```
add = lambda x,y: x+y
```

and

```
add = operator.__add__
```

So the question is: What really happens under the hood with `1/3.5` (or `1+3.5` or `1-3.5`)?

### Edit for the closure and about duplicate:

As seen in comments, this is ***not a duplicate*** of this question: [Operator overloading in python with the object on the right hand side of the operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490610/operator-overloading-in-python-with-the-object-on-the-right-hand-side-of-the-ope)
In my question I use out of the box types from Python, not custom made classes with overloads.

The question is about what's really happening when you use the operators (`+-*/`), due to the fact, using the first item class overload method doesn't always work as we may expect.

Comment: It's just calling `float.__rtruediv__`.

Comment: Int operations with a float argument on the right truly *aren't* implemented - ints know nothing about floats.  Returning `NotImplemented` gives the right argument a chance to handle the operation - and floats *do* know about ints.

Comment: @user2357112 not quite that, `float.__rtruediv__(1, 3.5)` returns TypeError.  The correct answer really lies at the interpreter level, specifically that `BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE` byte code opcode involved.

Comment: @metatoaster: You got the arguments in the wrong order. It's `float.__rtruediv__(3.5, 1)`.

Comment: Ah.  Nonetheless, there is some hidden intuition that may benefit from an answer, because the `__rtruediv__` did swap the arguments around... though I do recall there may be another canonical related to difference between operator on dunder methods that gets called by underlying bytecode opcode, might need to check for that first.

Comment: This was your first mistake: `div = int.__truediv__`.Dunder methods are *hooks*, they are not *equivalent* to the operators.  You shouldn't use them directly unless you are totally sure of the Python data model and how it works - often, you are meandering into implementation details that you should typically avoid. In this case, it isn't clear to me if this is documented, but you really need to [start with the data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Comment: In short, the protocol is that for the `__arithmetic__` dunder methods, you should return `NotImplemented` if it is not something the class knows how to handle. This essentially *defers* to an implementation that might exist on the type of the other operand. `int` doesn't know how to handle arithmetic with `float`, but `float` knows how to handle arithmetic with `int`. Similarly, for `complex`, the responsibility is on the class higher in the "tower" (so `complex` can handle `float` and `int`, but `float` and `int` defer)

Comment: I was unable to find a canonical SO thread about what really happens for a given statement, though to expand on the hooks, most binary operators in CPython are implemented via this [C macro](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.10/Objects/typeobject.c#L7104-L7150) (`truediv` is paired up [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.10/Objects/typeobject.c#L7408)); any binary operator basically tries the standard version or the `r` version (depending on the conditions as per the function produced by the macro), and return not implemented if it ultimately doesn't work.

Comment: `add = operator.__add__` is wrong, you mean `operator.add`. You should just use the `operator` module instead of `lambda x,y : x +y`, although they are equivalent the operator version is faster because it is implemented in C, whereas `x + y` has at least a couple of bytecode instructions on the interpreter

Comment: Let's answer specifically this: what is happening when `1/3.5` gets executed? Basically, `(1).__truediv__(3.5)` returns `NotImplemented`, so `(3.5).__rtruediv__(1)` is tried. That successfully returns the float `0.2857142857142857`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: `operator.__add__` exists and is equivalent to `operator.add`, so that part's fine.

Comment: @user2357112 hah never knew that.

Comment: I removed some parts of your edit since they didn't contribute to the question itself. For reference, see [What should I keep out of my posts and titles? (Meta SE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/343832). But I wanted to mention as well, the "private feedback" it's referring to is in the banner at the top of the page, starting with "Your post has been associated with a similar question", IIRC.

Comment: Out of the box types use the same tricks as custom types; it's using `__rtruediv__` just like a custom type would.

Comment: Did you read the docs for `NotImplemented`? *"When a binary method returns `NotImplemented` the interpreter will try the reflected operation on the other type ... See [Implementing the arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#implementing-the-arithmetic-operations) for examples."* And if you follow that link, there's some info about `__add__` vs `__radd__`, though it gets pretty technical.

Comment: @wjandrea nope, I didn't found that doc. Thanks for the hint! (and for massive question revision!)